# jQuery Validator: Validate form that is not attached to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm having trouble when I try to validate a form with the [jQuery Validator plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). So in this case, I have constructed a div table (not table elements, but divs styled as a table) where each row essentially is its own form complete w/ whatever form-controls.

Since this table could have potentially hundreds of rows however, I didn't want the overhead of wrapping each row element in its own separate form. So I came up with an idea where the save method just takes the row itself as an arg in order to create/validate/submit a form behind the scenes.

---

What I do is essentially clone the row and append the clone onto a new form I create like so

```
$("<form></form>").append(clonedRow);
```

---

Then I take the resulting variable (the form) and setup the validation. The validation options/setup look like this:

```
form.validate({
    rules: {
        Follow_Up_Code: { required: true, maxlength: 2 }
    },
    messages: {
        Follow_Up_Code: { required: "...", maxlength: "..." }
    },
    submitHandler: function(){...}
});
```

---

Currently I only want to validate against one input in this row to test. Here is the input markup:

```
<input type="text" class="get set input" name="Follow_Up_Code" style="width: 100%;">
```

---

After the form runs .validate(), I immediately submit the form. However, for my test case the form passes validation and runs the SubmitHandler set up in the validator every time.

This leads me to think that any form I want to validate with this plugin needs to be attached to the DOM in order to validate properly. However I've found no documentation on this. I would like to know if there is a way I could fix this, or if I'm better off trying to find/create my own validation service for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

After testing, I've come to discover that. Yes, the form needs to be attached to the DOM in some way shape or form. However, you can get around this pretty easily and unobtrusively:

```
form.css({ position: "absolute", visibility: "hidden", left: "-5000px" });
$("body").append(frm);
frm.submit();
```

That way the user won't be able to see or interact with this form while it's on the DOM.

---

This will get the job done and validate the form. In this case however, if there were any validation errors that I would want to show on the original table. I would have to access the invalid controls from inside the [validator's invalidHandler option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler) on setup. From there I just need to insert the error message(s) at where my desired location happens to be.

After all is said and done, it would be a good idea to .destroy the validator and remove that form from the DOM. I believe doing this at the end of both the submit handler and invalid handler would be the best way to go about that.